# Finding Native American Tribal Affiliation through DNA?

Tags: familytreedna.com, gedmatch.com, native-american

My husband is about 40-60% Native American, depending on which engine we run it through (Family Tree DNA or Gedmatch's various engines). His mother is from Ecuador, and his father is Mexican from the Sonora region, in which several tribes from Mexico as well as North America live (eg. Aztec, Pima, Seri, Apache, Yaqui, etc).

Are there any tribal DNA groups out there that we can join, similar to the Family Tree DNA Projects (eg. https://www.familytreedna.com/groups/mexico-amerindian/dna-results), in which you can compare DNA with others to try to narrow down more specifically which tribes?

GEDMATCH has a feature that estimates % of tribal DNA but that's as far as we've been able to get (analysis of autosomal show primarily Apache, Aztec, and some Southern California tribes).

We seek ways to find connections to specific tribes.

Comment: This is difficult for science to establish because ethnicity estimates are for thousands of years ago, not hundreds of years ago and the DNA markers used to estimate ethnicity come from samples in modern day communities. The DNA itself isn't for the ethnicity but more likely a region and likely as a result of environmental adaptation.

Answer (score -1):

I also found out that I am 34% Native American by doing my DNA on Ancestry.  That analysis said it was in Northern New Mexico. I know which region my mom's family lived in, so it was narrowed down some. Just in starting my family tree, I found out my great grandfather on my mother's side was born in the Pueblo there. I found him on an Indian Census Roll.  Perhaps you can just start researching your husband's family. With him being 40-60%, it can't be that far down the ancestry line!  I'm curious to find out about the DNA groups myself.